# Can you get the underlying type of an enum?

Tags: c++

I have the following `enum`:

```
enum enumLoanPaymentPolicy
{
    Unspecified = 0,

    InterestInArrears = 1 << 1,
    InterestInAdvance = 1 << 2,

    RoundUpRepayments = 1 << 3,
    RoundInterest = 1 << 4,
    RoundUpFlows = 1 << 5,
    RoundingMask = RoundUpRepayments | RoundInterest | RoundUpFlows,
};
```

Then elsewhere, given a value (`foo`) of this enumeration, I want to extract the bits set that are pertinent to `Round`.

I use `foo & RoundingMask` for that, but what *type* should I use?

Ideally I'd use `somethingorother(enumLoanPaymentPolicy) bar = foo & RoundingMask` where `somethingorother` is a bit like `decltype`. Is this even possible?

Comment: @LogicStuff Good find.  My google search didn't bring that up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [`std::underlying_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type)

example code from cppreference:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <type_traits>
>
> enum e1 {};
> enum class e2: int {};
>
> int main() {
>     bool e1_type = std::is_same<
>         unsigned
>        ,typename std::underlying_type<e1>::type>::value;     
>     bool e2_type = std::is_same<
>         int
>        ,typename std::underlying_type<e2>::type>::value;
>     std::cout
>     << "underlying type for 'e1' is " << (e1_type?"unsigned":"non-unsigned") << '\n'
>     << "underlying type for 'e2' is " << (e2_type?"int":"non-int") << '\n';
> }
> ```